# javascript automatic validation didn't work in php file

Tags: javascript, php, html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#email").blur(function() {
    var email = $(this).val();
    var valid = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/";

    if (email = "" || email == null) {
      $('#email-e').css("color", "red");
      $('#email-e').html('&#10060; Please Enter your email');
    } else {
      if (!email.test(valid)) {
        $('#email-e').css("color", "red");
        $('#email-e').html('&#10060; Invalid email address');
      } else {
        $('#email-e').css("color", "green");
        $('#email-e').html('Valid email address');
      }

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="test" id="email"><span id="emai-e"></span>
```

Comment: Show your HTML code too.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant rendered HTML and CSS and tell us what "did not work" means

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: `if (email = "" ` <- this is setting the variable, not comparing it. It should be `email == ""` or `email === ""` (for strict type comparison)

Answer (score 1):

1. `=` is assignment, not comparison, `===` is strictly equal and we can use that
2. It is regexp.test(text) not text.test(regexp)
3. You need to NOT quote the regexp

I changed the `var email =` to `const emailVal =`  since we have so many email around

```js
$(function() {
  const valid = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;

  $("#email").on("blur", function() {
    const emailVal = $(this).val();
    if (emailVal.trim() === "") { // field value is never null but can be empty
      $('#email-e').css("color", "red");
      $('#email-e').html('&#10060; Please Enter your email');
    } else { 
      if (!valid.test(emailVal)) {
        $('#email-e').css("color", "red");
        $('#email-e').html('&#10060; Invalid email address');
      } else {
        $('#email-e').css("color", "green");
        $('#email-e').html('Valid email address');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="test" id="email"> <span id="email-e"></span>
```

Shorter

```js
$(function() {
  const valid = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;

  $("#email").on("blur", function() {
    const emailVal = $(this).val();
    const empty = emailVal.trim() === "" // field value is never null but can be empty
    const isValid = !empty && valid.test(emailVal);
    let emailMessage = 'Valid email address';
    $('#email-e').css("color", isValid ? "green" : "red");
    if (empty) emailMessage = '&#10060; Please Enter your email';
    else if (!isValid) emailMessage = '&#10060; Invalid email address';
    $('#email-e').html(emailMessage)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="test" id="email"> <span id="email-e"></span>
```

Comment: I made you a shorter version. DRY

Comment: Can any one help me again if I am giving some part of my code?